# Box shadow is disappearing when added a new div tag

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and I am currently learning HTML and CSS. Now I am trying to create a webpage. In my html I have added a `box shadow` in the `header` tag. But when I am adding a `div` tag next to the `header` tag the box shadow is disappearing. Why is this happening?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  height: 101px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

header .logo {
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

header .logo img {
  width: 51px;
}

header .nav-bar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
}

header .nav-bar a {
  color: #000;
}

header .nav-bar a:hover {
  color: #008248;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-1 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-1 ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-1 ul li {
  margin-right: 24px;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul li {
  margin-left: 24px;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn, header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black {
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn:hover, header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black:hover {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black:hover {
  background-color: #4C4C4C;
}

.notice {
  background-color: #D8E8E3;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.notice p {
  width: 55%;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  font-size: 19.5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.75;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.notice p a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.notice p a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/starbucks-favicon.png">
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- FontAwesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Starbucks Coffee Company</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./images/starbucks-logo.png" alt="starbucks-logo">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <nav class="nav-1">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Rewards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <nav class="nav-2">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Find a store</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn" href="#">Sign in</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn-black" href="#">Join now</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="notice">
        <p>Facial coverings are now optional in our stores for our fully vaccinated customers, following CDC guidance, except where local regulations require it by law. <a href="#">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the new `<div>` is covering the box shadow on the `<header>`.  The solution I came up with was to give your `<header>` a [relative positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#relative) and a positive [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), which stacks it higher "vertically" in the z-axis:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  height: 101px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0 40px;
  position: relative; /* added position relative and z-index */
  z-index: 2;
}

header .logo {
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

header .logo img {
  width: 51px;
}

header .nav-bar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
}

header .nav-bar a {
  color: #000;
}

header .nav-bar a:hover {
  color: #008248;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-1 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-1 ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-1 ul li {
  margin-right: 24px;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul li {
  margin-left: 24px;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn, header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black {
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn:hover, header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black:hover {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black:hover {
  background-color: #4C4C4C;
}

.notice {
  background-color: #D8E8E3;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.notice p {
  width: 55%;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  font-size: 19.5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.75;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.notice p a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.notice p a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/starbucks-favicon.png">
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- FontAwesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Starbucks Coffee Company</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./images/starbucks-logo.png" alt="starbucks-logo">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <nav class="nav-1">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Rewards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <nav class="nav-2">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Find a store</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn" href="#">Sign in</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn-black" href="#">Join now</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="notice">
        <p>Facial coverings are now optional in our stores for our fully vaccinated customers, following CDC guidance, except where local regulations require it by law. <a href="#">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It *might* also be possible to view the shadow if the `<div>` that immediately followed the `<header>` had a `transparent` background, but since you have given it a specific background treatment that seemed like a solution that wasn't worth trying in this scenario.

**UPDATE**

Also, as [user G-Cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/g-cyrillus) points out in the comments, given that the `<div>` following the `<header>` has no explicit `position` (and thus has the default `position` value of `static`), the `z-index` here can actually be **omitted**.  You can see this below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  height: 101px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0 40px;
  position: relative; /* added position relative ONLY; omitted z-index */
  /* z-index: 2; */
}

header .logo {
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

header .logo img {
  width: 51px;
}

header .nav-bar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
}

header .nav-bar a {
  color: #000;
}

header .nav-bar a:hover {
  color: #008248;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-1 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-1 ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-1 ul li {
  margin-right: 24px;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul li {
  margin-left: 24px;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn, header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black {
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn:hover, header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black:hover {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

header .nav-bar .nav-2 ul .btn-black:hover {
  background-color: #4C4C4C;
}

.notice {
  background-color: #D8E8E3;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.notice p {
  width: 55%;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  font-size: 19.5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.75;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.notice p a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.notice p a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/starbucks-favicon.png">
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- FontAwesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Starbucks Coffee Company</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./images/starbucks-logo.png" alt="starbucks-logo">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <nav class="nav-1">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Rewards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <nav class="nav-2">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Find a store</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn" href="#">Sign in</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn-black" href="#">Join now</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="notice">
        <p>Facial coverings are now optional in our stores for our fully vaccinated customers, following CDC guidance, except where local regulations require it by law. <a href="#">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if the next tag is in static position or receives no transform rules, z-index is not needed , relative elements will be drawn on top :) z-index:2; can be remove here, but it's nice to advice it might also be needed. +1 anyway

Comment: @G-Cyrillus - excellent point, thanks! I have updated my answer with this detail.